# Kubernetes 64 bit cluster on Raspberry Pi 4

Tags: pi-4, 64-bit

I am trying to get Kubernetes installed (via kubeadm) on my Pi 4 cluster.

I do have it running, but it is all in 32 bit mode, which is challenging since so many K8s components are 64 bit only (for example, pod networks, persistent volume provisioning, etc). So it is possible to get a simplistic cluster running, but not one that allows "real work".

I've taken the steps via rpi-update and arm_64bit=1 in /boot/config.txt to get the kernel to 64 bit mode.

What steps are necessary to get either userland to arm64 - or more importantly to get K8s to arm64? (I'm fine with my userland being 32 bit, as long as my K8s cluster and Docker are 64 bit).

Comment: `What steps are necessary to get either userland to arm64` - wait ... because I don't think that's a possibility, yet, for raspbian at least

Comment: My "solution" is to abandon Raspbian in favor of Ubuntu, which has an arm64 version.

Comment: I recently did this and used Ubuntu 64 bit image. You can find detailed steps here: https://medium.com/@astrujic/step-by-step-slow-guide-kubernetes-cluster-on-raspberry-pi-4b-part-1-6e4179c89cbc